# Url Components does not show a proper url swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to get an api call, and I know that doing it with urlComponents is a good technique. Nevertheless, I do not really understand how it works.
Here is my call that I want to use:   `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?per_page=20;query=london&client_id=cn-xTwbvpcPUcpOgwJ2WIehB8UB641vs6GasCGMurzI`

Here is my call:

```
 func fetchNews() {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "api.unsplash.com"
    urlComponents.path = "search/photos?per_page=20"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "client_id", value: "cn-xTwbvpcPUcpOgwJ2WIehB8UB641vs6GasCGMurzI"),
                                .init(name:"", value: "London")]
    
    if let url = urlComponents.url {
        performRequest(url)
        print(url)
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How does your call not work? What is `performRequest`?

Comment: Why do you want to add a query item where its name is left blank?

Comment: I'm not sure `URLComponents` handles `;` in URLs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to debug more yourself, and check where it fails.

Let's starts with :

```
 func fetchNews() {
    var urlComponents = URLComponents()
    urlComponents.scheme = "https"
    urlComponents.host = "api.unsplash.com"
    urlComponents.path = "search/photos?per_page=20"
    urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "client_id", value: "cn-xTwbvpcPUcpOgwJ2WIehB8UB641vs6GasCGMurzI"),
                                .init(name:"", value: "London")]
    
    if let url = urlComponents.url {
        performRequest(url)
        print(url)
    } else {
        print("No URL")
    }
}
```

"No URL" is printed.

Let's remove the `queryItems` at all, still "No URL".

Let's fix it by adding `/` before the path.

And I get:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos%3Fper_page=20
```

What I see from your code and don't like: `per_page=20` that's a query item, and there is no key for "London", and the result percent escaped the `?` before `per_page`. So remove it, after all, it's the one indication that there will be query afterwards.

Let's change that to:

```
urlComponents.path = "/search/photos"
urlComponents.queryItems = [.init(name: "client_id", value: "cn-xTwbvpcPUcpOgwJ2WIehB8UB641vs6GasCGMurzI"),
                            .init(name:"query", value: "London"),
                            .init(name: "per_page", value: "20")]
```

Better, no?

Output:

```
https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=cn-xTwbvpcPUcpOgwJ2WIehB8UB641vs6GasCGMurzI&query=London&per_page=20
```

BUT, there is a ";" in your URL, and it's strange, it's unclear. You might add the "," after the `20` params, but order might import for it, whereas it shouldn't be for the query since it's a key access.